# mysql delete all rows with join

Tags: mysql, database, join

I have 2 tables:

Table 1 has 1 row for each user:

```
ID   startDate   EndDate
1    09-08-2015  09-08-2015
2    09-08-2015  09-08-2015
```

The second table contains multiple records for each user:

```
ID   UserID  data_key   data_val
1    1       "email"    "anything@test.com"
2    1       "name"     "John Brown"
3    2       "email"    "anything2@gmail.com"
4    2       "name"     "Tom Brady"
```

I am not using innodb so I cannot use cascade on delete. What I need to do is delete all records from both tables with a matching ID where `table2.data_key = "email"` and the data_val for that record`LIKE "%@test.com%"`. So in this case, table1 row1 will be deleted along with all rows in table 2 for UserID 1. All of my attempts thus far have failed. How can I make this happen, THANKS!!!

My latest attempt (I'm understanding why it doesn't work, but how to fix I am lost):

```
delete 
    table1, table2.* 
from table1  
    INNER JOIN table2 
    ON table1.ID = table2.User_ID
WHERE table2.data_key = 'email'
AND table2.data_val LIKE '%stringofinterest%' 
AND table1.ID = table2.User_ID
```

Comment: Well, Brendan, did you get it to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot delete rows from two tables simultaneously. You have to delete rows from one table first, and then from the other table.

However, I am not sure what you mean when you say "I am not using innodb so I cannot use cascade on delete." `ON DELETE CASCADE` is a feature of standard SQL, not a special feature of innodb, so unless you are using some totally lame excuse for an RDBMS, you should be able to do `ON DELETE CASCADE` just fine.

Comment: I believe in mysql innodb adds foreign key support. Without foreign key support I don't think a DELETE CASCADE is possible without the proper relationship. Please correct me if I am wrong here.

Comment: Let's stop talking about what innodb does, since you say you are not using innodb, and let's talk instead about precisely what it is that you are using.

Comment: MySQL using the MyISAM storage engine.

Comment: Oh, *that* poor excuse for an RDBMS!  Well, if you *must* use it, then it seems to me that two separate deletions will be necessary.  Wait to see if anyone else comes up with a better answer.